# SSL redirect .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

Installed SSL in hosting. after installing it tried to change redirect in .htaccess for getting https:// with greenpad lock symbol but not working what i have tried is just forcing https in htaccess files it was not working. Below is the .htaccess code already present with my script. In that i have added `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://` It was not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        Options -Indexes
        #RewriteBase /vrs7
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/l([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/l.$2 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/n([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/n.$2 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/p([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/p.$2 [R=301,L] 
#Adds trailing slash
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
        #Remove trailing slash
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?gclid=(.*) [OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?utm_source=(.*) [OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?fb_action_ids=(.*)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
        # Enforce www
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,QSA]
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
    </IfModule>
```

I was trying this for an custom php website. It was vacation rental script it has no option inside to add https:// in admin pannel. So that i am trying to implement it with the help of htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a site from `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =INSERTYOURSERVERNAMEHERE
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Replace `INSERTYOURSERVERNAMEHERE` with ... your server name, without protocol, i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you enable default-ssl

```
a2ensite default-ssl #this must be enable otherwise  will show
```

2. Did you allowoverride in the .htaccess file?

```
AllowOverride All
```